# Popen communicate vs Popen stdin.write()

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I am using a java engine to process some content.

I am wondering will it take up unnecessary resources like this.

```
command = 'some command to run my jar file'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comparing

```
output,err = p.communicate('some string that is passed to the java jar')
```

vs

```
p.stdin.write('some string that is passed to the java jar \n')
p.stdin.flush() 
output = p.stdout.readline()
```

To give some context to the problem. The strings are generated on the fly and hence i do not want to open and close the java application everything a string is generated.

So for example:

My python engine creates a string

'`Hi i am going home now`' which is passed to the java engine to run and obtains the output.

Next it produces '`He is going home now`' and the process repeats.

Obviously the java programs write to `System.out.println(output);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.communicate()` will wait for the process to terminate according to [the subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). Unless you plan to terminate and restart your java process each time you communicate, the second method (read/write) is all you have available.